# Energy levels for H atom

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, orbitals, atoms

Problem Statement:

> The number of orbitals (for H-atom) which have greater energy than $3p_y$ orbitals: $3s, 3p_z,3d_{z^{2}},3d_{x^{2}-y^{2}},2p_y, 4d_{z^2}, 4p_{y}$

The solution says that energies of all orbitals with same $n$ (principal quantum number) will be same, only for hydrogen atom.

Can someone explain why is that so? And when not to use the "$n+l$" thing?
[image: Image of the question]

Comment: In H atom, the energy depends only on the principal quantum number $n$. So 2s and 2p levels have the same energy. 3s, 3p and 3d have also the same energy. It is not the case any more for heavier atoms.

Comment: @Maurice but why is that the case, only for hydrogen? Also, will the answer be same for all 1 electron species, like He+ ?

Comment: @PurposeHonest It is not evident. You should prove that the bound-state wavefunctions that satisfy $\hat{H}\psi = E\psi$, have energy eigenvalues that only depend on the quantum number $n$. For the hydrogenic atom (1 electron + N protons), the solution still holds, but the energy eigenvalues will change because they are proportional to the squared value of the atomic number $Z$ and the reduced mass $\mu$.

Comment: @PurposeHonest. In a poly electronic atom, the interactions between the electrons depend on the shape of each orbital, i.e. on the non-principal quantum numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since (atomic) hydrogen has only one electron, there is *no electron-electron interaction* to differentiate internal levels.

Of course, an energy level *can* be split [if there is an external interaction](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydfin.html). See the [Feynman lectures](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_12.html) also. For example, in a magnetic field, the Zeeman effect splits spectral lines. The corresponding [Stark effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stark_effect) shows a similar splitting of levels in an electrostatic field.

Comment: And due the Lamb shift, ns and np electron energies are not the same even in hydrogen atom.

Comment: and there is spin-orbit coupling which is large and does split levels.

Comment: There seems to be no simple case. Even positronium has a complex spectrum... with a large peak at 511 keV in its death throes.